# Why aren't I able to identify NA in these ifelse statements?

Tags: r

I don't know if I'm going crazy or it's just late at night, but I can't understand why this isn't working. I start with a binary variable, with lots of missing data. I then try and turn it into a trinary variable such that it is 1, 0, or NA (placeholder of "testing" for now).

But for whatever reason, it never finds those results, despite the if.na() test working. What is going on here? I tried two different ways but it still doesn't work.

I simply want a trinary variable which is 1, 0 or "NA" as text (or, really, anything, ie "missing").

```
> data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress <- ifelse(data$DistanceKm_GuestAddress <= 25, 1, 0)
> table(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress, exclude = NULL)

    0     1  <NA> 
 3285   360 20766 
> 
> data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress_Trinary <- as.factor(ifelse(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress == 1, 1,
+                                                   ifelse(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress == 0, 0,
+                                                   ifelse(is.na(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress), "test", ""))))
> table(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress_Trinary, exclude = NULL)

    0     1  <NA> 
 3285   360 20766 
> data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress_Trinary <- as.factor(ifelse(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress == 1, 1,
+                                                   ifelse(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress == 0, 0,
+                                                   ifelse(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress==NA , "test", ""))))
> table(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress_Trinary, exclude = NULL)

    0     1  <NA> 
 3285   360 20766
```

Comment: How about just replace `NA` with another number? Something like: `df$var[is.na(df$var)] <- 9`

Comment: `tidyr::replace_na()`

Comment: My hunch is that `data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress` is of type factor. Try converting to character.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann It is of type double. I tried as.character'ing the references and no change.

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang Didn't work, which makes no sense to me. Table result was the same.

Comment: @Phil No change :(

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with some of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
as.factor(ifelse(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress == 1, 1, 
                 ifelse(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress == 0, 0, 
                        ifelse(data$Within25KmOfBuilding_GuestAddress == "<NA>" , "test", ""))))
```

Comment: I still get the same result, unfortunately.